# Determine all values of t for which the points lie on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into this problem, and don't really know where to start. The question was:
Determine all values of $t$ for which all these points lie on the same plane in $\Bbb R^3$, where
$$\begin{align*}
P&=(2,3,2)\\
Q&=(1,2,3)\\
R&=(t+1,3,t+2)\\
S&=(t,2t,2t+5).
\end{align*}$$

The help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any three distinct noncollinear points in $\Bbb R^3$ define a plane, so you may think of the plane spanned by $P,Q,R$. Fix a chosen point on that plane, say $P$ and consider the vectors $q = \vec{PQ} = Q - P$ and $r = \vec{PR} = R - P$. Computing the cross product $n = q \times r$ yields a vector $n$ perpendicular to the plane, the so called *normal*. Given that vector a point $S$ lies on the plane if and only if the vector $s = \vec{PS} = P - S$ is perpendicular to the normal (ie parallel to the plane), which amounts to having the dot product $s \cdot n = 0$.

Summarizing: Find $t$ such that
$$(S-P) \cdot ((Q-P) \times (R-P)) = 0.$$

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you very much for your help. :))